Bash のキーコマンド C-q,C-v はなぜ挙動が違うのか
Bash マニュアルによると、「入力文字をそのまま追加する」コマンド quoted-insert は C-q, C-v の二か所に割り当てられています。
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Text.html
端末内でもコマンドが割り当てられているのを確認しました。
~$ bind -p | grep quoted-insert
"\C-q": quoted-insert
"\C-v": quoted-insert

ただ、実際にキー入力を行うと C-v は想定どおりの挙動でしたが、もう一方の C-q は単純にキー入力が無視されているようでした。
例えば C-q の後に C-h を入力すると文字 ^h ではなくコマンド backward-delete-char が実行されます。
Ubuntu on WSL2, Ubuntu Server など複数の環境＆端末で試してみて、いずれも同じ結果だったので、自分の環境だけの問題ではないと思います。
どうして C-q, C-v が異なる挙動をする（ようにみえる）のか知っている方はいますか？

C-q が端末のフロー制御に割り当てられていないでしょうか。
% stty -ixon
でフロー制御を無効化すると C-q が C-v と同じ挙動になるかもしれません。
